# PLSQL efficient way to iterate over words in clob

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with markup text stored in a clob.
I would like to iterate and check a property word by word. 
What is the most efficient way to do that?
Pseudocode is like this, I get body from the table.

```
declare
myvar VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
myvar := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(body,32000,1);
--pseudocode
FOR i IN SPLIT(myvar)
-- do something for i
END FOR;
END;
```

Comment: Do you have to worry about multi-byte characters?  That can make the solution more complicated.

Comment: @Jon Heller: no, not really.